# How to keep line-break in array value of Annotation

Tags: java, eclipse

It has the following annotation.

```
@HogeAnnotation({"aValue", 
    "bValue", 
    "cToooooLooongValueee"})
```

In Code-Formatter of Eclipse, them will be one-line.

```
@HogeAnnotation({"aValue", "bValue", "cToooooLooongValueee"})
```

for this behavior not desirable, I want to know the way that keep line-break.

If possible, instead of a method of suppressing the code format(e.g.`/* @formatter:on */`), want to solve the by configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Preferences --> Java --> Code Style --> Formatter --> Line Wrapping --> Never join already wrapped lines`